# Adding mysql driver to tomcat openshift

Tags: mysql, tomcat, drivers, openshift-online-2

I have deployed my war file on openshift tomcat. 
As suggested to deploy war file directly we need to remove the src and pom.xml before coping the war file in webapps folder. [pre compiled java applications (WAR and EAR files) onto your OpenShift](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740)

Now since my application uses mysql driver - when tomcat starts on open shift it throws error of mysql driver classses not found.

How else can I add the mysql driver to openshift tomcat. Putting them in the web-inf/lib directory does not work since the datasources are configured on tomcat context.xml

Comment: You can download mysql drivers from http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.tar.gz upload it in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory, and then restart your tomcat